# Remaining close votes error in dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, voting-limits

As my question title says, Please check the below image.

[image]

As shown in the above screenshot, I am voting on low quality posts to put on hold. I am getting wrong number of remaining votes. Unless, I misunderstood, I think this is an issue in SE.

### Update:

I think its not fixed properly. Please check the below screenshot:

[image]

Still, displaying the count of remaining votes two times. Isn't it Ambiguous?

Comment: It looks like the number with background is the amount of close votes remaining and the other number is amount of flags remaining. Somehow they got mixed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, i am also thinking the same. But that is not correct way of displaying the count of Remaining close votes... This should be fixed..

Comment: Of course it's not correct, hence it was edited as a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in rev 2013.8.13.1336 (meta) / 2013.8.13.935 (sites)

Comment: Not really, still showing the same number twice (e.g. 22 22 remaining). Should just be the number with background and "votes remaining" next to it, like it was before. Or better yet the number then "close votes remaining" to be consistent with the flagging dialog.

Comment: oh, I just fixed the mis-matching numbers... will be fixed shortly

Comment: Nice. No juicy details explaining what happened? (don't think it's due to templates or localization this time! :))

Comment: ... to be continued :)